# Data se pierde cuando uso un macro definido por mi como función para transmitirla por puerto serial

Tags: c, macros, serialport, stm32

cómo están?. Tengo problemas con una función realizada con #define ya que la data que deseo enviar vía serial se corrompe antes de ser enviada por el puerto, lo que estoy haciendo aquí es adaptar las librerías de una pantalla nextion las cuales vienen para arduino y así poder utilizarlas en un STM32 con las librerías HAL. El archivo donde defino la función nexSerialE(a) es el siguiente

```
/*
 * NexConfig.h
 *
 *  Created on: 10 oct. 2020
 *      Author: valery
 */

 /**
 * @file NexConfig.h
 *
 * Options for user can be found here.
 *
 * @author  Wu Pengfei (email:<pengfei.wu@itead.cc>)
 * @date    2015/8/13
 * @copyright
 * Copyright (C) 2014-2015 ITEAD Intelligent Systems Co., Ltd. \n
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of
 * the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 */
#ifndef __NEXCONFIG_H__
#define __NEXCONFIG_H__

#include "usart.h"
#include "main.h"
/**
 * @addtogroup Configuration
 * @{
 */

/**
 * Define DEBUG_SERIAL_ENABLE to enable debug serial.
 * Comment it to disable debug serial.
 */
#define DEBUG_SERIAL_ENABLE

/**
 * Define dbSerial for the output of debug messages.
 */
#define dbSerial Serial

/**
 * Define nexSerial for communicate with Nextion touch panel.
 */

/**
 * Define como handler serial el UART 1
 */
#define nexSerial1  huart1

/**
 * Define como handler serial el UART 2
 */
#define nexSerial2  huart2

#define nexSerialE(a)   HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&nexSerial1, a, sizeof((char *) a))

#ifdef DEBUG_SERIAL_ENABLE
#define dbSerialPrint(a)    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&nexSerial2, a, sizeof((char *) a))
#else
#define dbSerialPrint(a)    do{}while(0)
#endif

/**
 * @}
 */

#endif /* #ifndef __NEXCONFIG_H__ */
```

Tengo otro archivo de librería llamado nexHardware.c donde está definida la función sendComand(* cmd) la cual es como sigue

```
void sendCommand(char *cmd)
{
    uint8_t cEnviar[Long_Rec] = {0};
    sprintf((char *) cEnviar, "%s\xFF\xFF\xFF", cmd);
    nexSerialE(cEnviar);
}
```

cuando llamo esta función desde el main y aunque el arreglo cEnviar[] tiene almacenados los datos correctos, al usar el macro nexSerialE() con el argumento cEnviar, como se puede observar en la siguiente imagen la trama almacenada en el arreglo cEnviar es la correcta incluyendo los tres 0xFF

[image: Dato correcto a enviar]

después de terminar el envío se encuentra que lo enviado por el microcontrolador es lo que se puede observar en la siguiente imagen

[image: Datos incorrectos enviados]

en realidad si envía una cantidad de caracteres igual a los que deseo enviar pero no son los caracteres correctos, solo que la aplicación terminal virtual no reconoce los caracteres y por eso no los imprime pero si se pueden ver en el destino y lo que llega es lo siguiente: pa\x01 \x8C \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x7F.

En el main.c el código ejecutado es el siguiente:

```
char mEnviar[] = "page estado";

int main()
{
    __asm("nop");
    sendCommand(mEnviar);
    while (1)
    {

    }
}
```

Si en cambio no llamo a la función sendCommand sino que utilizo la función de envío vía serial de la librería HAL para los STM32 entonces si envía la trama con los datos correctos. Lo que no entiendo es por qué se está perdiendo la data a enviar si el macro lo que realmente contiene es la función de la librería HAL.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar para resolver el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que te está ocurriendo no está relacionado directamente con la macro en cuestión sino con un error en la forma en la que invocas `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()` dentro de esa macro. Quizás ese error no lo tienes cuando la invocas "directamente" y por eso ves un comportamiento diferente.

La llamada que haces es esta (una vez expandida tu macro):

```
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, cEnviar, sizeof((char *) cEnviar));
```

y el problema es el `sizeof((char *) cEnviar))`, ya que debido al casting `(char*)` lo que estás obteniendo mediante `sizeof()` es el tamaño de un puntero y no el tamaño del array o la cantidad de bytes que haya en él.

El tamaño de un puntero es algo fijo, que depende de la arquitectura. Si por ejemplo en tu arquitectura los punteros son de 32 bits ocuparían 4 bytes, por lo que ese `sizeof()` te devolvería siempre 4 con independencia de los bytes que tengas en `cEnviar`. Así que estarías enviando sólo 4 bytes.

A juzgar por los resultados que muestras parece que en tu arquitectura un puntero sea de 16 bits (me extraña un tamaño tan pequeño, la verdad, sólo 2 bytes, pero ya que estás trabajando con microcontroladores podría ser...) Digo esto porque en la cadena recibida sólo aparecen correctamente los dos primeros bytes "pa", y el resto es "basura" que posiblemente estuviera ya ahí en el buffer de recepción.

La solución sería usar `strlen()` así:

```
#define nexSerialE(a)   HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&nexSerial1, a, strlen(a))
```

`strlen()` cuenta cuántos bytes hay en ese buffer hasta la aparición del primer byte de valor 0. Ya que previamente usaste `sprintf()` para rellenar el buffer, esta función habrá dejado un 0 al final de la cadena, así que `strlen()` funcionará perfectamente.

Otra opción (dependiendo de qué necesites exactamente) es poner `sizeof(cEnviar)`, lo que es en el fondo equivalente a poner `Long_Rec`, pues ese es el tamaño de ese buffer. En este caso enviarías siempre el buffer completo, con independencia de que contenga menos caracteres. Supongo que no es esto lo que quieres.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, fíjate que cambié el sizeof() por strlen() para que deje de imprimir una vez que llegue al EOF y surge el mismo problema de imprimir los dos primeros caracteres y luego basura cuando utilizo cEnviar como argumento del macro nexserialE() a su vez expandido a HAL_UART_Transmit_IT() con sus respectivos argumentos,

Comment: en cambio si declaro en nexHardware.c como un externo al arreglo mEnviar[] y se lo coloco como argumento directamente al macro nexserialE() de la forma nexserialE(mEnviar) entonces de esa forma si envía la trama almacenada en el mEnviar declarado en main() completamente y sin errores, con el sizeof(cEnviar) también me da exactamente el mismo resultador erroneo, la única forma en que me funciona con el strlen(cEnviar) es cuando copio el contenido de la función sendCommand() al main y lo ejecuto desde ahí, es decir:

Comment: `uint8_t cEnviar[Long_Rec] = {0};`
 `sprintf((char *) cEnviar, "%s\xFF\xFF\xFF", mEnviar);`
 `nexSerialE(cEnviar);`. Con ese código ejecutado desde el mai funciona a la perfección por alguna razón pareciera como que se pierde el direccionamiento después de asignar el puntero dos veces y no tengo idea de por qué pasa eso dentro de la función.